# How to undo the changes that Excel made to a .txt file

Tags: excel

I opened a .txt file using Excel. I was asked if the file was delimited and some other settings. Then the file opened and the text was fine. I saved the file but when I opened it again strange characters were shown and I couldn't retrieve the original text even when I opened the file with NotePad.

How can I get the original text back?

Comment: You probably used Save As and told it to save it as an excel file but kept the .txt extension.  Try renaming the file with a .xlsx extension and see if you can open it in Excel

Answer (score -1):

Ur file changed from .txt to .xlsx or ( .xlsm , .xls ...) you need to rename it to .txt form again ,but still there is a chance your file is destroyed